# Printing ls -la in HTML file

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a bash script. I need to print a list of files with date stamp and the size of the file in html.

This is what I'm trying:

```
for i in $(ls directory); do 
echo $i "<br>" >> file.html
done
```

How can I format the list of files ?

Comment: [Don't use `$(ls *)`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), just use `for i in *; do`. Also, use [`stat`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) to get file info -- you can pass it a format string that tells it how to format the file's into.

Comment: `*` is _not_ "the directory", it expands to the filenames in the current directory.

Comment: @glennjackman sorry about my explanation, it was a symbol as an example. I have already edit it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, don't parse the output of ls as you may encounter issues with spaces in filenames. A better approach would be to use find. Find also allows you to print the output in the format you require. So using a html table to print the output:

```
echo "<html><table>" >> htmlfile
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "<tr><td>%f</td><td>%s</td><td>%Tc</td></tr>\n" >> htmlfile
echo "</table></html>" >> htmlfile
```

Print the opening html/table tag to a file called htmlfile. Then run a find command that searches for all files in the directory and prints the filename, size and modification date (locale format) surrounded by table row/cell tags. Append this output to the htmlfile . Finally print the closing html tag of the table.